Why does ExportAsFixedFormat fail with no error?
I've got a VBA macro that takes a range in my spreadsheet and converts it into a PDF. Or at least, it should! I'm running VBA 7.1 in Excel from Microsoft 365 Apps for Enterprise.
Here is the sub-routine in question:
Sub rangeToPdf(printRange As String, strFilename As String, strTitle As String)
    Dim topMarginInches As Single
    topMarginInches = 0.6

    If (InStr(strTitle, vbLf) > 0) Then
        ' Title goes over a single line, so need to bump the margins to make space
        topMarginInches = 1
    End If

    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = strTitle
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(topMarginInches)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.6)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = True
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlPortrait
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = 100
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With
    
    Application.PrintCommunication = True

    ' Prints the specified range to a PDF with the selected filename.
    Range(printRange).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strFilename
    
End Sub

Unfortunately, this is consistently failing when I run it on my computer! I've stepped through it in the debugger, and I can see that we run the Range(printRange).ExportAsFixedFormat command, but it appears to be a no-op! Nothing happens and we continue to the next line. This is confusing to me, as I would have expected that there would be some kind of error pop-up if there was something normal wrong (for example, the directory not existing, or being read-only, or something of that nature). I've done a check to see if there's any way we might have some error handling catching the exception, but I can't see anything.
I have seen this exact macro work fine on a co-worker's PC, but for some reason it will not do so on mine! Does anyone know what might cause this problem?

Add MsgBox Range(printRange).Address(1, 1, 0, 1) as first line and check it is the correct sheet.

I had a go at that - the ranges it is printing out are sensible ones and there's nothing about them that would explain why no document is printed (they're approximately 24 rows by 5 columns each, nothing in them that seems dodgy).

Try commenting out Application.PrintCommunication = False If that makes the problem "go away" then uncomment but put a DoEvents after Application.PrintCommunication = True - I'm thinking along the lines of the printer cache not "catching up" before the ExportAsFixedFormat is called

But don't you see any pdf file named as strFilename? In fact, what does Debug.Print strFilename return? If the path is not correct, the document may be saved in Documents... What does Debug.Print Dir(strFilename) return?

Please share the code of the calling procedure. We can't see what you're feeding this sub with. Using ActiveSheet, especially in a called procedure, is a bad idea. Add a worksheet parameter to the signature i.e. Sub rangeToPdf(ws As Worksheet, ..., ..., ...), replace the two occurrences of ActiveSheet with ws and prepend ws. to the last line i.e. ws.Range(.... Then if you must use the Activesheet, use rangeToPdf ActiveSheet, ..., ..., ... in the calling procedure. It is always better to use something like rangeToPdf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1"), ..., ..., ....

❌ @CHill60 Commenting out Application.PrintCommunication = False didn't make a difference.
❔@FaneDuru Interestingly when I added debug statements I can see that (a) strFilename is correct (although note that the file doesn't exist yet - I'm trying to create the PDF file as part of this process), but Dir(strFilename) returns an empty string. Perhaps because the file doesn't exist yet, so there is no valid pathname for Dir() to operate on?
@VBasic2008 I'll give your suggestion a try and report back - thanks!

Does it work if you print to pdf manually ? Are you printing to network eg onedrive ?

Application.PrintCommunication = False not only needs to be removed but you may need to call Application.PrintCommunication = True to reset the property.  Application level properties tend to be held onto, so you have to make sure that their state is correct once the Sub of Function executes.

I eventually got to the bottom of what was going on here - thanks to the suggestion from @CDP1082 to see what happens when I try and export manually. Turns out that the Sensitivity Label was set to Confidential, and that meant when I attempted to export to PDF there was an error message indicating that the file "hadn't been saved with the new sensitivity level". I tried reducing the Sensitivity Label on the document, at which point I was able to run my export macros with no issues!
It's not an ideal answer - in the long run you want these Sensitivity Labels to remain correct and consistent. But in the short run I can run my macros to generate the PDFs I need and then toggle the Sensitivity back to Confidential if I need to.
Thanks to everyone for their help!
